# Detect [w/out using a UIWebView] if www.awebsiteaddress.com needs to have http:// or https:// on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am writing an application that lets the user specify a website URL in a textfield. As I gave the app to testers I noticed that most users will not naturally enter the "**http://**" or "**https://**" part of a website url, and when told they need to enter the url scheme before "www..." they get frustrated and some don't even know it.

So, once the user enters the url to a site in the textfield, if they did not specify either "http://" or "https://", I want the app to prefix the url entered by the user with the correct scheme, either "http://" or "https://".

When in an iOS app how can I know the correct scheme the website url needs to have so that I can simply prefix the string entered by the user with the correct url scheme?

So, this was marked as a possible duplicate. I can see how it could be perceived as such. However, my intention is not to make the URL work in a UIWebView, my main goal is to actually detect what the correct scheme is before trying to load the url in a UIWebView. So, the possible duplicate feedback is actually wrong. I want to know how to find the correct scheme without having to load the site through a WebView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect whether UIWebView needs to use HTTP or HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211991/detect-whether-uiwebview-needs-to-use-http-or-https)

Comment: Make the call to the website using http:// and check if it succeeds. If it fails then call again but with https://.